# How to get product order by two custom taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: custom-taxonomy, database, mysql, wpdb

Yesterday i stuck in the middle of code that how could  i retrieve product belong to specific custom taxonomy ordered by other taxonomy.

```
Table wp_posts:

 id    |  post_title
----------------------
 2     |    Galaxy S4
 4     |    Iphone i5
 6     |    Nokia lumia 535

 Table wp_term_realtionship:-

 object_id |  term_taxonomy_id
 -----------------------------
      2    |      12
      4    |      12
      6    |      12
      2    |      15
      4    |      16
      6    |      17

  Table wp_terms:-

   term_id   |   name
   -------------------
     12      |   Smartphone
     15      |   Samsung
     16      |   Apple
     17      |   Nokia
```

Now Smartphone is from product_cat and brands (samsung,apple,nokia) from product_brand taxonomy. Now if user goes to smartphone category and order by brand (A to Z) what query should i write. The code which i tried so far:-

```
Code:
 SELECT * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.id=wp_term_relationships.object_id INNER JOIN wp_terms wp_terms.term_id=wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id WHERE wp_terms.term_id=18 ORDER BY wp_terms.name DESC;
```

Now above code result product of smartphone category but not in order by product brand. Please help me to rectify above code. 
Thanks.

Comment: This should be aan edit to your previous question

Comment: @PieterGoosen yeah may be. But i cant find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is notoriously against ordering by terms. Of course it's precisely what people need to accomplish in practice. And precisely a mess with a very clunky database representation of them (which is planned to be slowly improved over several releases to be fair).

In a nutshell the issues with your query are:

- it's preferable to work with `WP_Query`, even if you are considerably customizing SQL
- you are missing the whole third `wp_term_taxonomy` table :)

While I don't think there is any truly canonical way to do it, the most reliable approach I had seen and used is covered in [Sortable Taxonomy Columns](http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html) post.